# remove duplicate values from a oracle sql query's output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a situation where I want to remove the duplicated record from the result by using sql query in oracle 10g. I am using regular expression to remove the alphabets from the result

> Original value = 1A,1B,2C,2F,4A,4z,11A,11B

Current Sql query

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE( tablex.column, '[A-Za-z]' , '' )
from db1
```

gives me the following output

> 1,1,2,3,4,4,11,11

how can i remove duplicate from the output to just show unique values 
i.e.

> 1,2,3,4,11

Comment: You could use the Distinct keyword

Comment: Clarifying: `select distinct REGEXP_REPLACE( tablex.column, '[A-Za-z]' , '' ) from db1`.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks bob, but that will remove duplicate row, not the duplicate content in a row , may be i wasn't clear enough while describing  the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your table contains strings with values separated with commas.

You can try something like this:
[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43cdb/71)

```
select rtrim(xmltype('<r><n>' || 
               replace(REGEXP_REPLACE( col, '[A-Za-z]' , '' ), ',', ',</n><n>')||',</n></r>'
              ).extract('//n[not(preceding::n = .)]/text()').getstringval(), ',')
from tablex;
```

What it does is after using your `regexp_replace` it makes a xmltype from it and then uses `XPATH` to get the desired output.

If you also want to sort the values (and still use the xml approach) then you need XSL

```
select rtrim(xmltype('<r><n>' || 
               replace(REGEXP_REPLACE( col, '[A-Za-z]' , '' ), ',', '</n><n>')||'</n></r>'
              ).extract('//n[not(preceding::n = .)]')
.transform(xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" ?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:template match="/"><xsl:for-each select="//n[not(preceding::n = .)]"><xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/><xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:for-each></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>'))
.getstringval(), ',')              
from tablex;
```

But you can also try different approaches, such as splitting the tokens to rows and then recollecting them

```
select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, n || ',') order by to_number(n))
              .extract('//text()'), ',')
from(
SELECT distinct rn, trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level)) n
  FROM (select row_number() over (order by col) rn ,
               REGEXP_REPLACE( col, '[A-Za-z]' , '' ) col
        from tablex) t
CONNECT BY instr(col, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
)
group by rn;
```

Comment: Thanks , its worked with with one issue , it returned the value 1,2,3,4,11,2,8, 

Is it possible to remove the comma from the last value i.e. 1,2,3,4,11,8 not 1,2,3,4,11,8, 


any chance we can get the output in sorted order i.e 1,2,3,4,8,11 not 1,2,3,4,11,8